# Is teleop_twist_keyboard launchable in ROS2?

Tags: ros2, roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
fairly new to ROS2 I am currently trying to work with launch files.
I was trying to simply launch the teleop_twist_keyboard but it would't work.

> ```
>     launch_ros.actions.Node(
>         package="teleop_twist_keyboard",
>         node_executable="teleop_twist_keyboard",
>         output='screen',
>         node_name='teleop')
> ```

I don't get an error message, and the topic node connections in rqt look right too. Although I don't the usual console output (telling me which keys I should use). Is this package launchable yet? What can I do?

I am working with dashing.
Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/337885/is-teleop_twist_keyboard-launchable-in-ros2?/) by [relffok](https://answers.ros.org/users/49523/relffok/) on ROS Answers with karma: 169 on 2019-11-18

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mlanting](https://answers.ros.org/users/2091/mlanting/) on 2019-11-27**:
have you tried running the launch command with the -d option for more debug output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Update: After adding the  prefix  `'xterm -e'` to launch in a new terminal everything worked as it should.

```
launch_ros.actions.Node(
    package='teleop_twist_keyboard',
    node_executable="teleop_twist_keyboard",
    output='screen',
    prefix = 'xterm -e',
    node_name='teleop')
```

---

Originally posted by [relffok](https://answers.ros.org/users/49523/relffok/) with karma: 169 on 2020-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pmuthu2s](https://answers.ros.org/users/33024/pmuthu2s/) on 2021-02-10**:
I feel this has a work around ! Does anyone have an idea on how to do it without xterm -e?

**Comment by [KimJensen](https://answers.ros.org/users/53265/kimjensen/) on 2021-10-11**:
I'd also like to know, how to run this teleop node without using 'xterm'?

**Comment by [KimJensen](https://answers.ros.org/users/53265/kimjensen/) on 2021-10-11**:
As is stated here, then I do not believe it is possible to do it without using 'xterm': [ros2/teleop_twist_keyboard/issues](https://github.com/ros2/teleop_twist_keyboard/issues/21)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For the record, in an xml launch file, it would look like this:

```
  <node pkg="teleop_twist_keyboard" exec="teleop_twist_keyboard" name="teleop" output="screen" launch-prefix="xterm -e" />
```

This solution requires having the xterm package installed.

---

Originally posted by [eldeivid](https://answers.ros.org/users/84703/eldeivid/) with karma: 31 on 2021-09-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1